# Why is this text occluded by this button?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

As you can see, I have a text UI element and a button. The button's Pos Z is set to 0 (in Rect Transform) and the text's Pos Z is set to -25 (putting the text "in front of" the button.) But the text appears to be occluded by the button. Why is this so, and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unity Engine UI system renders UI objects top to bottom as placed in hierarchy .This means that if text is placed above button in hierarchy then text will be rendered at last and then the button. You can solve this by moving button above text in hierarchy :[image: Before :]

[image]